# Ошибка при запросе git pull origin upstream

Tags: git, github, git-remote, git-pull

У меня есть форк определенного репозитория. Я хочу получать изменения из оригинального репозитория. Сделал git clone из форка, затем всё по инструкции:
https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/

Затем при выполнении:

```
git pull origin upstream
```

Получаю сообщение об ошибке:

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref upstream
```

Что я сделал не так, и как это исправить?

Comment: git fetch upstream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Синтаксис такой:

```
git pull откуда имя-ветки
```

Вы пытаетесь получить с `origin` ветку `upstream`, там такой ветки нет. Попробуйте так:

```
git pull upstream master
```

Это сработает только если вы не меняете ветку `master` в своем репозитории, то есть если вы делаете коммиты в другую ветку. Если нет, сработает так:

```
git fetch upstream
```

Теперь в ветке `upstream/master` у вас есть состояние ветки `master` в репозитории `upstream`. Те самые изменения из оригинального репозитория.